# Filemaker server BUG: backup schedules DISAPPEAR after restart of host machine. Workarounds?

Tags: macos

Some time ago I discovered my Filemaker backup schedules mystically disappear. After some research I find out it happens right after restart of host machine.

Eventually I found [this post on official filemaker forum](http://forums.filemaker.com/posts/c7bcbff1df)

> There is a major Schedules bug in FMS 12.0v3 that is happening on a brand new machine with a clean install of everything. This bug is preventing my client's databases from backing up properly (which is probably the most important requirement of all -- current backups). I don't know how to solve it, and my client is out $2,000 on a brand new machine.
>
> My client was having this EXACT problem on an old FileMaker Server
>   machine, so he decided to spend $2,000 on a brand new iMac running
>   10.8.2 to replace his old machine. We thought that throwing money at the problem would solve the problems, but it didn't work because this
>   is a bug in FMS 12.0v3.
>
> Completely brand new machine, straight from the Apple Store. We didn't
>   do ANY migrations of anything… no migration of FMS settings, no OS X
>   Migration Assistant, nothing. We simply installed FileMaker Server
>   12.0v1, updated to FileMaker Server 12.0v3, installed the latest Java, manually dragged his FileMaker files into the Databases folder, set
>   the permissions manually, and opened them in FileMaker Server.
>
> So far, so good.
>
> The problem is with the Schedules. I created 4 Schedules to backup all
>   the databases on a daily basis, and I manually tested all 4 Schedules
>   by right-clicking on each one and choosing "Run Schedule". All of them
>   completed perfectly fine. They all backed up the databases just fine.
>
> However, after I Stop FileMaker Server (using the Stop button in the
>   Admin Console, with a countdown time of 0 minutes) and I restart the
>   machine, one or more of the schedules WILL COMPLETELY DISAPPEAR from
>   FileMaker Server!! The schedules just completely delete themselves,
>   never to be found again!!
>
> And, for the schedules that DO somehow luckily remain in FileMaker
>   Server, they no longer show a "Last Completed" date anymore. They've
>   completely wiped out any history of their previous successful backups.
>   I don't even know if they will run again at their scheduled time. But
>   after each time I stop FileMaker Server & restart the machine,
>   Schedules will start deleting themselves.
>
> This is hugely problematic, because backups are of mission critical
>   importance. This is on a brand new machine, just a few hours old, with
>   ABSOLUTELY NOTHING on the machine except for FileMaker Server and
>   Java. No migration of any data from anywhere… databases &
>   configuration settings were manually moved over.
>
> This is the cleanest & purest testing environment ever, and yet this
>   serious major bug is still happening.

And I just don't know what to do in this case, how should I make automatic backups?

Should I relinquish Filemaker server's scheduling completely, and start using 3rd party automatic software (say, "Time Machine" since I have Mac).

Or maybe I should make some sort of notification for system administrator? ( Startup Banner with text: "Filemaker schedule is corrupted and needs to be restored manually" )

Did anyone face this bug, too?

UPD I reapaired disk permissions, but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you try the "repair permissions" fix suggested in that thread?

Comment: @Ladadadada Yes, I did.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution for this problem. Check your settings in the "Security & Privacy" Control-Panel. If your settings are on "Anywhere" by "Allow Applications Downloaded from" put it back to "Mac App Store and idetified developers" recreate your schedules in FMS and do a restart again. My schedules then kept in place. But be carefully. Do not reimport any exported FMS schedules. They will disapear again. Only way I could reuse some exported schedules was when I imported them while the settings where on "Anywhere" and then set the settings back to "Mac App Store and...". If I did it like this they kept in place. Hope this helps you.

Update: Some further test's where bringing some further strange behavior. While I was investigate this issue I created a home directory for the fmsadmin user but cleared it out afterwards because I was thinking this is not the solution for the Issue. But after a reboot the schedules dissapeared again. I recreated then a home directory for the fmsadmin unser (did this in Workgroup Manager for 10.8 which is to seperatedly installed from Apple) and then the schedules I newly created kept in place. So you probably have to play through some different setups to get back in business.

Regards

Fix